# How do I facilitate longer and even growth?

Tags: diagnosis, houseplants, plant-health, watering

I would like to know if I should cut off the leaves in the middle to facilitate longer and even growth to match the sides? 
The 2 sides are growing but as you can see, it is yellow. Should I spray water on it? Are those roots or stems? 
I have also just bought a bigger pot to repot the plant. The pic below is in old pot.

Thank you!

[image: notice the 2 sides]

Answer (score 5):

What a lovely little pothos.  Those are adventitious roots.  Do not mess with this plant, don't cut the leaves off or those roots.  It is beautiful.  To make a THICKER denser plant the best way to do that is to pinch off the apical or terminal roots.  I just do not see any problem with this guy whatsoever.

I am glad you've decided to up pot this guy.  Needs it amazingly tough plant.  Do not get a pot larger than 6" in diameter.  Perhaps in a year you'll need to up pot this guy again but do not go too large too quickly.

Use bagged sterilized potting soil.  Do not use garden soil.  No rock or gravel at the bottom of the soil above the drainage hole.  Just bagged potting soil.  Water well and allow the soil to dry before watering again.  This plant would also love a 'shower' once every couple of months.  Put in shower, turn cold water on and allow to 'rain', cleaning off the leaves and soaking the soil.  Turn off water and allow to drain.  Shake the plant a bit before putting it back in its normal place.

You do know that this is a vine, not a shrub type plant, yes?  And one of the best plants for indoors.  During the summer this guy and any indoor plant could use some outdoor time on a covered porch.  Helps produce more food to be stored in the roots for winter and makes indoor plants last longer and thrive.

A little osmocote twice per year and you are good.  No need to spray or prune at all.  New foliage is always lighter and yellowish.  When was the last time this plant had fertilizer?  Osmocote 14-14-14 extended release fertilizer, half the label dose twice a year is all this guy needs...as well as bagged sterilized potting soil.  Water well, then allow to dry before watering again.  A hanging pot might be a good idea as this plant keeps on lengthening as a vine.

Comment: Thank you very much stormy! I'll just leave the plant alone and water it as usual.

Comment: Do up pot your plant.  The reason for the extra roots is because this plant is looking to expand its territory (needs more soil).  This is one of the plants that seems to do best when sort of ignored.  But give it the best in soil and you'll be dealing with a gorgeous vine!

Comment: By the way, I'm currently using an essence once every 2 weeks for the plant as it claim to work as a fertiliser. I also plan to water maybe twice every week after I transfer it to soil. Will try out the 'shower' advice you mentioned earlier. Hope it helps in healthy growth and will update soon ! Thanks stormy! :)

Comment: Brenda, please tell me what an 'essence' is?  Truly, Osmocote is like the simplest, best way to fertilize indoor plants for newbie use to be successful.  Just because someone or some article 'claims' something works well doesn't mean that that is true.  Our media makes me mad.  Send the formulation of this 'essence' and a way so that I can go take a peek.

Comment: And...watering twice per week might be too much once you transplant it into a larger volume of soil.

Comment: Feeding it with Essence of plant food. Contains plant growing factors and hormones. Could be why the plant is growing longer. Will also try once a week watering and see how it grows.